# Google Cloud Dataprep Union

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I have two datasets in my dataprep flow that i am trying to union. 
I am getting an error message that one of the dataset is broken and to fix before attempting a Union.Could someone advise what would be the best way to union two datasets?
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide more details such as the exact error message, a data sample or a screenshot? Also, can you use that dataset in a recipe without performing the union step?

Comment: Sure, i am getting a message: "There is a problem with the data upstream "the_name_of_the_dataset" is broken. Please fix it before attempting to union. But i can run the two datasets separately and they look fine.

Comment: The union might be impacted by changes made in that dataset on a previous recipe. Docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Fix-Dependency-Issues_57344608) include some steps in how to fix dependency errors. If that does not help you can provide more information or open an issue on the [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190822).